# error 0103 using a switch statement with cross script strings in Unity (C#)

Tags: c#

what im trying to do is test a public string named enemyBehaviorStatus that exists on another script in this function, and swap the material accordingly. I can reference the function on the other script, but when i try to make the switch statement test the enemyBehaviorStatus it gives me error 0103: name 'enemyBehaviorStatus' does not exist on line 28 (switch (enemyBehaviorStatus))

Thank you for the help much appreciated

this is the colorchanging script

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class ChangeMaterialColor : MonoBehaviour
{
    
    public GameObject enemy;
    public Material Material1;
    public Material Material2;
    public Material Material3;
    
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }
    
    public void swapMaterial()
    {
        switch (enemyBehaviorStatus)
        {
            case "passive":      
        enemy.GetComponent<MeshRenderer> ().material = Material1;
            break;
            
            case "agressive":      
        enemy.GetComponent<MeshRenderer> ().material = Material2;
            break;
            
            case "wounded":      
        enemy.GetComponent<MeshRenderer> ().material = Material3;
            break;
            
            default:       
        enemy.GetComponent<MeshRenderer> ().material = Material1;
            break;      
        }
    }
}
```

this is the enemy behavior script with enemyBehaviorStatus in it

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.AI;

public class EnemyNavAI : MonoBehaviour
{
    
    public Transform agentGoal;
    private NavMeshAgent nmAgent;
    public string enemyBehaviorStatus = "passive";
    
    
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        nmAgent = GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>();
        this.GetComponent<ChangeMaterialColor>().swapMaterial();
        //nmAgent.destination = agentGoal.position;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (enemyBehaviorStatus == "agressive")
        {
             nmAgent.destination = agentGoal.position;
             this.GetComponent<ChangeMaterialColor>().swapMaterial();
        } 
        
        if (enemyBehaviorStatus == "wounded")
        {
            //nmAgent.destination = agentGoal.position - (gameObject.tag == "Player").position;
            this.GetComponent<ChangeMaterialColor>().swapMaterial();
        }
    }
    
    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.tag == "Player")
         {
        nmAgent.destination = agentGoal.position;
        enemyBehaviorStatus = "agressive";
        this.GetComponent<ChangeMaterialColor>().swapMaterial();
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing this code is part of a class (which you don't show) + that `enemyBehaviorStatus` exists in some code of either the same class *or* of another class (which you don't show either). How are the two parts related? How is this code supposed to know about that variable? You need to **[edit]** the question and include all relevant details. Right now we see only a rather incomplete part of the whole.

Comment: im sorry i didnt show all of the code i edited the post is that good? thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

The swapMaterial() method needs to take in the string as a parameter unless enemyBahaviorStatus is a class property.

So essentially:

```
swapMaterial(string enemyBahaviourStatus) {...}
```

OR

```
Public string enemyBahaviourStatus;
```

(and a value is assigned somewhere else in your code).

Comment: I edited the code to show the entirety of the problem, can you take a look and see what the issue is? thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if this is the best method, but i did fix it by making a string called `enemyStatus` in the color changing script and assigning it to equal:

```
enemy.GetComponent<EnemyNavAI>().enemyBehaviorStatus;
```

I then just inserted `enemyStatus` into the switch testing () and it works as intended. Colors change when `enemyBehaviorStatus` changes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `enemyBehaviorStatus` as a parameter to the `swapMaterial` method:

```
public void swapMaterial(string enemyBehaviorStatus)
{
    // ...
}
```

And then pass it every time you call `swapMaterial`:

```
this.GetComponent<ChangeMaterialColor>().swapMaterial(enemyBehaviorStatus);
```

This should work, and (in my opinion) is also the preferred approach:

- If A wants B to do something that needs a value X, and A has the X, then A should pass X to B.
- In your answer you make B responsible to go look for an instance of A (assuming or hoping there is an A), and then to fetch the X from it (assuming or hoping that this A contains the X that it needs and not some other X).